# How can I get ggpairs to display ancova results in upper panels?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, anova, ggally

I'm making a scatterplot matrix with ggpairs{GGally) as follows, but I'd like to display the p values for each term in my aov results in the upper panels, rather than just the overall and by-species correlation value that comes with the package.

How can I get the right column from this aov result into my upper plots? Can I write a custom function to do this, and how? Is is even possible using ggpairs? Thanks.

```
library(GGally);library(ggplot2)
pm <- ggpairs(data = iris, 
          mapping = aes(color = Species),
          columns = c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width"))

pm
```

[image: iris data ggpairs plot]

```
result <- aov(Sepal.Length ~  Sepal.Width*Petal.Length, data = iris)
print(summary(result))

                      Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
Sepal.Width                1   1.41    1.41    12.9 0.000447 ***
Petal.Length               1  84.43   84.43   771.4  < 2e-16 ***
Sepal.Width:Petal.Length   1   0.35    0.35     3.2 0.075712 .  
Residuals                146  15.98    0.11                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```